# Django model class methods for predefined values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on some Django-code that has a model like this:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.CharField(maxlength=255)
```

There are about 10 pre-defined code/text-pairs that are stored in the database. Scattered around the codebase I see code like this:

```
status = Status.objects.get(code=0) # successful
status = Status.objects.get(code=1) # failed
```

I would rather have a method for each so that the code would look something like this instead:

```
status = Status.successful()
status = Status.failed()
etc...
```

Is this possible? I have looked in to the Manager-stuff but I haven't really found a way. Is it time to really RTFM?

In Java it would be a static method and in Ruby you would just define a method on self, but it's not that easy in Python, is it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should perhaps implement this by defining a custom manager for your class, and adding two manager methods on that manager (which I believe is the preferred way for adding table-level functionality for any model). However, another way of doing it is by throwing in two [class methods](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) on your class that query and return resulting objects, such as:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.CharField(maxlength=255)

    @classmethod
    def successful(cls):
        return cls.objects.get(code=0)

    @classmethod
    def failed(cls):
        return cls.objects.get(code=1)
```

Do note please that `get()` is likely to throw different exceptions, such as `Status.DoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

And for an example implementation of how to do the same thing using Django managers, you could do something like this:

```
class StatusManager(models.Manager):
    def successful(self):
        return self.get(code=1)

    def failed(self):
        return self.get(code=0)

class Status(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.CharField(maxlength=255)

    objects = StatusManager()
```

Where, you could do `Status.objects.successful()` and `Status.objects.failed()` to get what you desire.

Comment: Manager method is the way. Not only is very flexible, but also very expressive!

Comment: Pardon me if it is a stupid question, but what is the harm in defining these methods in the model directly without creating any additional managers? That would just register the methods under the default manager. Unless you want to switch managers depending on circumstances, and thus implement different sets of methods, it should work, should it not?

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta: There is no harm in doing it the way you describe, as far as I know. However, keeping such methods reserved for managers conforms to Django's conventions and helps keep things clean, because methods in managers work against a particular table, while methods in models work against a particular record or row. If your requirement is to operate over a table, then a manager is the Django way to go about doing it.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta just it s architecture choice default manager by convention is objects... you can add as many as you want... if you are using django 1.7 is better to subclass QuerySet so you can chain queries and you can do objects = CustomQuerySet.as_manager()...